# Move text around a fixed overflowing element in another z-index layer

Tags: html, css, text, overflow, css-position

Situation:
I have a fixed image in my template that overflows the content. Because it's fixed, sometimes the image overflows text. Is there a method that fixes this and makes the text go around the image, as if it is `float`-ing inside the content div.

See the [html-example](http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/).

CSS answer is preferred, Javscript/jQuery answers are acceptable.

*Some extra details:*

- The content is random. It can be long, short, contain images and have html.
- The `#cloud` has to stay on the same position with any content.

> The issue isn't visible on the live website anymore, because it's solved by putting #cloud in a lower z-index layer.

Comment: Is the image positioned absolutely?  If you can just float the image to the right, then the text would wrap automatically.

Comment: Div is absolute outside of the content. If you have checked the example, you would have known..

Comment: I did check the example. I meant if it has to be absolute. Ideally, you'd want to fix it so that it's coded better.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question. Since the absolute element is part of the design, it cannot move around. Putting the image inside the content with a float attribute would make it's position variable. Because sometimes the content is long, sometimes it's short.

Comment: Here's what I was talking about... the image can always stay in the same position as well. http://jsfiddle.net/abpYb/2/

Comment: Awesome idea! It would work to put a dummy-div on the spot that the absolute image is overflowing (see http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/7/ ). The only problem is that if my users insert an floating image in their content, that it will be cleared as well (see http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/8/ ).

Comment: Can you just change the overflow of the parent element of the clouds to be `overflow:hidden;` that way the clouds look like they go behind the container, rather than over it? (I'm basing this off the live site example)

Comment: I asume u mean z-index. This is possible but wouldn't be as pretty ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [CSS Exclusions and Shapes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/). This is relatively new and not widely supported by browsers. You might also be interested in this great [article on CSS Exclusions](http://galjot.si/css-exclusions).

Comment: Really would love to have this feature

Comment: Me too, never heard of this before, but it looks amazing.

Comment: Since all other answers didn't solve the problem and this answer should solve it in the future, I think this is the best answer.

Comment: I think the best best real world fix (for now) for you would be changing the design.
You could add some right padding to the text div, move the cloud a bit to the right, or make it (somewhat) transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pG3AG/

The cloud div had to be relatively positioned, not absolute since absolute positioning causes the element to position according to the viewport instead of relative to other elements (like the content element in this case). Also, the right:20px positioning of the box needed to be decreased or removed so that last letters from 'unfinished' words in the line don't end up behind the cloud box.

Hope this works out for you!

Comment: As you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/ the `#cloud` is outside the content. Also the content has random value, making it impossible to add an image in the middle of it.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of managed to solve it for the JS Fiddle example with JQuery (sorry, couldn't come up with a CSS solution)

```
var _top = $('#cloud').offset().top;
var _left = $('#cloud').offset().left;
var _height = $('#cloud').height();

var _contentTop = $('#content').offset().top;
var _contentLeft = $('#content').offset().left;
var _contentWidth = $('#content').width();

var _floatWidth = (_contentLeft+_contentWidth)-_left
    var _floatTop = _top-_contentTop;

$('#content').prepend('<div id="virtual" style="float:right">&nbsp;</div>');
$('#virtual').css('margin-top',_floatTop).css('width',_floatWidth).css('height',_height);
```

Basically, I'm adding in a hidden div floated to the position of the cloud so it sits in the content, shoving the text around, where the cloud appears in the foreground.

Looking at the content on the website you linked to, you may need to shift the div into the surrounding container and play with the numbers a little, but it more or less works here http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/58/

Comment: i think this would be the best way

Comment: Also a nice solution compatible with all recent browsers, only problem is that this also 'shoves' all the text before the cloud. I made this extra visible on http://jsfiddle.net/cLnz6/96/ .

Comment: Hmm... yeah, you're right, hadn't taken that into account. Sorry. I'm pretty much out of ideas

Answer (score 1):

if i understand

(http://jsfiddle.net/VG4Ef/1/)

```
body{
    background-color: #8888FF;
}

#container{
    float:left;
    width: 400px;
    background-color:#CFCFFF;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#content{
    background-color: #FFDFDF;
    width: 340px;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left:
}

#cloud{
    width: 130px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:right;
    top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 12px;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-100px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    background: yellow;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

personally, what I would do is Shrink the cloud a little bit, that cloud is plenty big enough to do that with. then I would put those clouds in a Fixed Div with a Transparent Background so that they would stay with the screen, making it look like they are floating.

Second thing. if the first isn't an option.  I would put the cloud behind the main feed by changing the `Z-index`  there is nothing on that little tip of a cloud and other clouds in the background are behind the feed as well so I wouldn't imagine that it would raise any questions if that little tip of a cloud is hanging behind the feed.

Comment: This is escaping the problem, not solving it ;-)